# ALC897 not working with Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: sound, 22.04, realtek

My headset mic is not working and the right side is mute.

It seems ALC897 works only with Windows.

Anyone knows the solution for those issues?

My motherboard is MSI PRO B660M-A DDR4. The headset is an Asus TUF Gaming H3.
The SO is Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Update: I tried a headphone and it worked. Then I realized the 3.5mm connector of my headset does not fit my case (Antes 300), properly. After pulling it all the way it gets pushed back. I'll test later with a mobile headset to verify the mic.

Comment: How is the headset connected to the computer? Bluetooth, wire, custom dongle?

Comment: Wired, at the front. The case is an Antec 300, I tested a headphone that worked. Then I noticed the headset connector gets pushed back after inserting it.

Comment: The issue was the case connector. After pushing it harder it worked. It was years without use, maybe that was the case. Thanks a lot @David!!